# Data binding to memory map for real-time chart updating

Tags: c#, charts, real-time, memory-mapped-files

I have a process that generates data points (I have multiple values stored in an class object for each point) that I would like to plot real-time as they are created.  I have thought of using a memory-map to save the data using the System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles library.  The process generating data and the charting form will be on separate threads and cannot be syncronized.  My only thought for accessing the data for charting would be to create a timer on the form that finds out-of-data data points, adds them to the chart data series, and re-draws that chart.  I have not tried this yet because I am worried about read/write access errors since the threads are not syncronized.  There is a possibility that zero or ten values could be appended to the memory-map resource on each timer event.  I would hope that I can re-draw the chart at 20-30 hertz.

Is it possible to data-bind to memory mapped files?  Can anyone hint to some resources that can help me decide the right methods of writing and charting the data?

Comment: What advantage do you expect from using `MemoryMappedFile` over just an array of points?